# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Spark Job for StringBuffer.append()

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, stringbuffer

I am trying to form a Tuple2 of X,StringBuffer using mapToPair function  from a Map.entry of X,StringBuffer. (X is user defined Object) The code is as follows:

```
JavaPairRDD<X, StringBuffer> d = data_obj
            .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Map.Entry<X, Object>, X, StringBuffer>() {
                public Tuple2<X, StringBuffer> call(Map.Entry<X, Object> S) {
                    Tuple2<X, StringBuffer> temp_map = null;
                    if (S.getValue() != null) {

                        StringBuffer temp = (StringBuffer) S.getValue();
                        temp_map = new Tuple2<X, StringBuffer>(S.getKey(), temp);
                    }

                    return temp_map;

                }
            });
```

Firstly this process takes around 8 mins for an input size of 2.3 GB of data. Moreover in the next step, where I use reducebyKey, I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

```
JavaPairRDD<X, StringBuffer> Data = d.reduceByKey(new Function2<StringBuffer, StringBuffer, StringBuffer>() {
                public StringBuffer call(StringBuffer s1, StringBuffer s2) {
                    return s1.append(s2);
                }
            });
```

I have 12 nodes each having 64 GB of memory and 2 6 core processors.
I submit the Spark job with the following configurations:

```
 spark-submit --class main class --master master port --deploy-mode client --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseParallelGC" --driver-memory 24g --executor-memory 40g --executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=1" --conf "spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout=700" --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096" --conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=8192" --conf "spark.shuffle.compress=true" <.jar> file  arguments
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: How much data (worst case) is in the `StringBuffer`? If you have one (or several) keys reoccurring a large number of times, your `StringBuffer` for those keys may end up eating up you memory. You have to remember that the size of a single partition has to fit in memory - otherwise you will get OOMs.

Comment: I am not quite sure you should use a `StringBuffer` to store your values here. This could lead to over-use memory while you perform the reduce operation, because you are keeping the concatenated intermediate values of every of the "reduce by key" operations. In other words, I suspect that if for a key `K` you have a total of `n` characters, you may end up with O(n^2) as memory usage for your key `K` while Spark is processing your RDD. Maybe try with pure `String` instead? What drove you to use `StringBuffer` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes the StringBuffer can have a little less than 10MB data. What should be my alternative? Eventually I copy these StringBuffers to a text file. But initially when I build this how can I store the values?

Comment: @SGh: ok, is it possible to try with a `String`? From your code, I cannot see where the `StringBuffer` actually comes from? Where do you create them?